# How to configure route on the basis of url parameters from different application.

Tags: angular, angular-routing

There are 5 links on java application, when user click on those, then each link will open each angular form on the basis of parameters passed on those links. How do I configure my route for this scenario in angular.

Comment: Whether the user clicks on a link coming from a Java application or directly enters the URL in the address bar doesn't change anything: you configure your routes according to the rules defined in the documentation. What have you tried, and what is the concrete problem you faced?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this scenario you can implement with below steps :

In your application create all 5 routes which are required, pass that route name in your links in a parameter.

In your Java Application: create all 5 URLs Like  :

http://youapplication.com/authenticate?name=routeName

So here Authenticate is predefined component & routes in my application so all links will throw on the same route and inside ngOnInit method based on parameter Name we will redirect to that routes.